# Does a goal kick have to be specifically be from the edge of the goal area or can it just be anywhere inside the area?

Tags: rules, football

Does a goal kick have to be specifically be from the edge of the goal area, or can it just be anywhere inside the area? I've seen goalies taking them from somewhat inside the area, so I wondered if this was actually how it works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A goal kick **MUST** be taken from within the *goal area* (note that this is the "six yard box", not the "eighteen yard box", formally called the *penalty area*).

[IFAB Law 16 - The Goal Kick, 1. *The Procedure*](http://theifab.com/#!/laws/the-goal-kick/chapters/the-goal-kick-procedure)

> - The ball must be stationary and is kicked from any point within the goal area by a player of the defending team
> - The ball is in play when it leaves the penalty area
> - Opponents must be outside the penalty area until the ball is in play

There are further details about what can and cannot happen during or after completing a goal kick in [IFAB Law 16 - 2. *Infringements and Sanctions*](http://theifab.com/#!/laws/the-goal-kick/chapters/the-goal-kick-infringements-and-sanctions).

---

[IFAB Law 1 - The Field of Play, 5. *The Goal Area*](http://theifab.com/#!/laws/the-field-of-play/chapters/the-goal-area) dictates the dimensions of the goal area as:

> Two lines are drawn at right angles to the goal line, 5.5 m (6 yds) from the inside of each goalpost. These lines extend into the field of play for 5.5m (6yds) and are joined by a line drawn parallel with the goal line. The area bounded by these lines and the goal line is the goal area.